# Unable to get the mock WebSocket client running

Tags: node.js, websocket, jestjs

I am unable to get the client running. For some reason the test timesout saying

> thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test

The client is always in the connecting mode thus never get connected. Due to this I am unable to test the websockets functionality.

**wsServer.test.js**

```
const { startServer, waitForSocketState, createSocketClient } = require("./webSocketTestUtils");
const {WebSocket} = require('../__mocks__/ws');


const port =3000;
describe("WebSocket Server", () => {

    let server;  
    beforeAll(async () => {
      server = await startServer(port);
         });  
    afterAll(() => server.close());  
    
    test("Server echoes the message it receives from client", async () => {
      const [client, messages] = await createSocketClient(port, 50);
   
      const testMessage = "This is a test message from mr.x";    // Send client message
      client.send(testMessage);    // Perform assertions on the response
      await waitForSocketState(client, client.CLOSED);
     
      const [responseMessage] = messages;
      expect(responseMessage).toBe(testMessage);
    });


  });
```

**wsServer.js**

```
const {Server} = require('../__mocks__/ws');


async function createWebSocketServer(server) {
    const mockServer = new Server({server});
    mockServer.on('connection', socket => {
        socket.on('message', message => {
            socket.send(message);
        });
      });
  }

module.exports =  {createWebSocketServer};
```

**webSocketTestUtils.js**

```
const http = require("http");
const { WebSocket} = require('../__mocks__/ws');
const {createWebSocketServer} = require("./wsServer");

function startServer(port) {
  const server = http.createServer();
  createWebSocketServer(server);  
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    server.listen(port, () => resolve(server));
  });
}

function waitForSocketState(socket, state) {

    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        if (socket.readyState === state) {
          resolve();
        } else {
          waitForSocketState(socket, state).then(resolve);
        }
      }, 5);
    });
  }


async function createSocketClient(port, closeAfter) {
    const client = new WebSocket(`ws://localhost:${port}` );
    await waitForSocketState(client, client.OPEN);
    const messages = [];  
    client.onmessage = data => {
      messages.push(data);    
      if (messages.length === closeAfter) {
        client.close();
      }    
    };
    
    return client, messages;
  }
module.exports = { startServer, waitForSocketState, createSocketClient };
```

****mocks**/ws.js**

```
const {WebSocket, Server} = require("mock-socket");
module.exports = {WebSocket, Server}
```

**Directory Tree**

```
websockets
  | __mocks__
    | ws.js
  | __tests__
    | wsServer.test.js
    | wsServer.js
    | webSocketTestUtils.js
```

**Dependencies**

```
"jest": "^28.1.3",
"jest-websocket-mock": "^2.3.0"
```

Would be great if someone can help out, TIA.

Comment: In your wsServer.test.js, immediately after this line => expect(responseMessage).toBe(testMessage);.....put a comma after the closing curly brace and increase the time. e.g.
 
expect(responseMessage).toBe(testMessage);
}, 10000);